# How to perform a join between two tables in Big Query by using sub string function in the join clause

Tags: sql, regex, bigdata, google-bigquery

I have some input data as below from two tables where I need to join both of them to extract some result out of it. Please go through the details as below for the same.Any inputs/thoughts would be appreciated.

```
Table A
ColA,ColB
abc,1
def,2



Table B
ColA,ColC
abc_,45
abc*,67
def_,23
def,12
```

Now I need to join both tables A,B on ColA to extract the result. The complex part which I am facing here is I would like to ignore the *,_  then join both tables and get the final result as below.

**`Expected Result :-`**

```
abc,1,45
abc,1,67
def,2,23
def,2,12
```

**`What I have tried?`**

```
SELECT A.ColA AS ColA,
       A.ColB AS ColB
       B.ColC AS ColC
  FROM TableA A
JOIN EACH 
       TableB B
    ON A.ColA = B.ColA; 

 -- SUBSTR( B.ColA, 1, LENGTH( A.ColA ) ) 

Comments :- The above join clause using SUBSTR function is not supported in Big Query.
```

Comment: `JOIN ... ON B.ColA LIKE A.ColA + '%' ...` or `JOIN ... ON B.ColA LIKE CONCAT(A.ColA , '%' )`

Comment: Is the `JOIN` condition `ON A.ColA = SUBSTR( B.ColA, 1, LENGTH( A.ColA ) )`?

Comment: @SOaddict Did you try `LIKE`?

Comment: Nope.. Can you elaborate on it...

Comment: Tried using LIKE operator in ON Clause.. I get the below error ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Comment: One very inefficient way you can do is cross join two tables and filter in WHERE using SUBSTR/LIKE

Answer (score 5):

Try transforming the column before JOIN, so you can do an equality JOIN:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc
FROM [tablea] a
JOIN (
  SELECT LEFT(cola, 3) cola_x, colc
  FROM [tableb]
) b 
ON a.cola=b.cola_x
```